# Windows 8.1: Editing and refreshing items in the Apps view

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu, start-screen

Apps view of the Windows 8.1 start screen maps from the following folders:

```
shell:common start menu\programs    (affects all users)
shell:start menu\programs           (affects current user)
```

Therefore  it  is possible to edit the Apps view items and categories by editing the program shortcuts in this folders.

This is often advertised in many forums and it is much like the previous Windows versions' Start Menu.
The problem is that to make changes effective one needs (normally) restarting Windows.

Another *non-orthodox* possibility would be to restart the Windows Explorer process in the Task Manager.

In Windows 7 everything was immediate!
I think there should be a better way to trigger the Apps screen refresh.

Comment: There isn't.  It doesn't require restarting Windows.  It just requires the user to be logged out.  Are we talking about Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.0 because their behavior in this regard will be different and you have tagged your question as both.

Comment: @Ramhound: 8.1, I didn't know they were different even in this.  I edited the question.